# Access last logged value in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

When I evaluate an expression directly in the Chrome Console like

```
1 + 1
```

then I can reference to the evaluated value using

```
$_
```

[image]

However, I can't access the value with $_, when the value is a result of a console.log, coming from inside of my application, instead of an expression I typed directly into the console.

[image]

Is there a way to access the last evaluated expression, regardless where it came from?

Answer (score 78):

After it's been logged to the console, you can right click on it and get an option to Store as global object.  Clicking this will define a new variable like 'temp1' which will point to the variable. [Here's a video of it in action (not mine)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qALFiTlVWdg).

Answer (score 14):

Just follow these steps:

1. Click over the result with right button
2. Save as global variable
3. copy(temp1)

Comment: It saved me here.

Comment: Im glad it helped you

Answer (score 3):

You can only copy & paste.

See all available commands and shortcuts:

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts

Comment: Is c&p really an option, when the evaluated expression is e.g. an object?

Comment: console.log() outputs a string - so no, you can't get an object from it. You should use the debugger for that.

Comment: It is not true that `console.log()` outputs a string, at least in Chrome. It accepts an arbitrary object and obviously retains a reference to the actual object because it allows you to inspect attributes of the object and its subobjects to arbitrary depth. To test this, evaluate something like `console.log((function(){var o={};o.recurse=o;return o;})());` in the console.

Comment: @user4815162342 nice find - however that still allows you only to view the object, not to assign it.

Comment: @hcris It also gives one hope that it might be somehow possible to get a hold of the object. :)

Answer (score 1):

A work-around for this is to define a variable in the global namespace.  Presumably, your `console.log(local_variable)` is inside a function.

```
<script>
  var global_variable = null;

  function some_function() {
    var local_variable = 0;
    global_variable = local_variable;
    console.log(local_variable);
  }
</script>
```

Here, when `some_function()` is called, your `local_variable` will be logged, but you can then type `global_variable` in your console to get its value quickly and work with it.

Comment: or shorter `console.log((window.temp = local_variable))`

Answer (score 1):

You *could* access any evaluated expression at any point in execution with Chrome's DevTools by setting breakpoints.

Your logged expression should have a clickable line number in the console - follow the link, then set a breakpoint on the line of code (which should be your `console.log`).

Full guide on breakpoints:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints